# how to add variable link in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a remote php file located on a server

`https://webserver.com/file.php`

and i have several images in html file on another server that are linked through

```html
<div class="apps">
    <a href = "file.php?type=1"><img src="https://anysite.com/image.jpeg" alt="image" border="0"></a></br>
    logo
</div>
```

i want to replace the main link with a variable and add it to my images.

should appear link the following:

```html
<div class="apps">
    <a href = "$variable?type=1"><img src="https://anysite.com/image.jpeg" alt="image" border="0"></a></br>
    logo
</div>
```

and the final link of the image will be:

https://webserver.com/file.php?type=1

Anyone can help please?

the html code is as follows:

```html
<html> 
    <head> </head>
    <?php 
    var $variable = "https://webserver.com/file.php";
    ?>
    <body>
    <div class="apps">
    <a href = "$variable?type=1"><img src="https://anysite.com/image.jpeg" alt="image" border="0"></a>
    logo
</div>
<div class="apps">
    <a href = "$variable?type=2"><img src="https://anysite.com/image2.jpeg" alt="image2" border="0"></a>
    logo
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls write some code you tried to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's PHP, not Javascript question. You try something like this?

```
<div class="apps">
    <a href = "<?php echo $variable; ?>?type=1"><img src="https://anysite.com/image.jpeg" alt="image" border="0"></a></br>
    logo
</div>
```

EDIT:

complete example:

```
<?php 
    $variable = "https://webserver.com/file.php";
?>
<html> 
    <head> </head>
    <body>
    <div class="apps">
    <a href="<?php echo $variable; ?>?type=1"><img src="https://anysite.com/image.jpeg" alt="image" border="0"></a>
    logo
</div>
<div class="apps">
    <a href="<?php echo $variable; ?>?type=2"><img src="https://anysite.com/image2.jpeg" alt="image2" border="0"></a>
    logo
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i assign a variable in the <head> section and add the url to the variable? it can be like this? $variable = "https://server.com/file.php"

Comment: I think you need to read basic principles of PHP and HTML. Good practice for StackOverflow it's study, read, teach and coding, and when I get problem what I really can't solve then I ask.

Comment: well it's not that complicated though, i just want to replace file.php link with a variable not more. it  doesn't matter how it can be done.

Comment: it's dependent if you want be a developer or want only fix this code ;) because you mixin PHP principles with Javascript - it's different language and environment.

Comment: i want to just solve this piece of code only, any language that solves it i'm okay with it

Comment: I edit my answer, w/o explain, because I think you don't care about "why" ;)

Comment: lol thank you dear for your help, but it didn't work, the variable was not replaced by the url.

Comment: if you still see `<?php ...` in output HTML, then check your server and PHP module - simple test - write `test.php` with content `<?php echo "Working"; ?>`, if is in output it's not only `Working` your server it's broken.

Comment: i have tested the code on xampp on my local machine, the code inside the href didn't work, only the php echo worked. can it become in java script instead of php?

Comment: what about this? <a href="{!'https://' + sometext}">Click me</a>

Comment: what is this? i don't know this syntax, i mean it's not javascript or php